# How to store an event is happening from 2017-08-20 to 2017-08-24? What data type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Say an event is happening from 2017-08-20 to 2017-08-24.

I've actually seen most APIs store and return this like:

```
date_start: date
date_end: date
```

However it might just be the case that these APIs are using MongoDB or some other NoSQL without types.

Should I be doing the above or using the data types `interval` (not sure of an example of what it's for) or `daterange` (seems likely) instead?

Answer (score 2):

[Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) might be the best - either daterange, tsrange or tstzrange

> > **8.17.1. Built-in Range Types**
>
> PostgreSQL comes with the following built-in range types:
>
> int4range — Range of integer
>
> int8range — Range of bigint
>
> numrange — Range of numeric
>
> **tsrange** — Range of timestamp without time zone
>
> **tstzrange** — Range of timestamp with time zone
>
> **daterange** — Range of date

GiST and SP-GiST indexes can be created for table columns of range types.
You can create cxclusion constraints for ranges which allow the specification of constraints such as "non-overlapping" on a range type.
There are many b[uilt-in functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html) available for range types.
The only drawback is that ranges are not a part of SQL standard and they are not supported by other databases, you may have troubles if you decide some day to move to another RDBMS.